# What repair options exist for iPhone 5s

Tags: iphone

I bought an iPhone 5s about 3 days ago. Unfortunately I've discovered that the headphone jack is broken.

The left side of my headphones doesn't produce sound. I tried the headphones in another device and they worked fine. So the problem lies with the iPhone 5s.

When I took it back to the store, I was told it would take 2 weeks to get it fixed because they had to send it away for repair.

What options do I have to get it fixed?

Comment: The answer provided is vague since you haven't narrowed down what country your sale was transacted. That will give you rights as a consumer as well as help narrow down your options if you decide the store isn't helping. In my experience, only people that get very angry or have unreasonable demands can't work out a proper exchange on their second visit - but who knows what happened in your case as even a great person can have a bad day and need a do-over. (Whether that person is the consumer, manager, or service tech).

Comment: Looks like he's from Sweden, so likely purchased from there. And in regards to the question, user69252, can you please tell us where exactly you purchased the device? Was it from a legitimate Apple Store retail outlet? Typically Apple will give you a new device right then and there should you visit a Genius with a hardware fault. We simply do not have enough information right now to help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you bought the phone from an official Apple retailer, and it is new and within the warranty period, then there should be no issues with returning the phone for a refund or replacement.

The sales policies of Apple are at http://www.apple.com/legal/ and http://www.apple.com/legal/sales-support/sales-policies/retail.html

What complicates matters in many cases is the carrier. Unless you purchased an unsubsidized phone, you may have the carrier balk at a return and have to wait for them to clear your subsidy.

In the meantime, the issues sounds like the phone connector jack internal to the phone, you could attempt a DIY repair by inserting the headphone connector and giving it a good wiggle and spin about in the socket, this could get it working. If not, then read up on the policies and see if the store is willing to work with you to find a solution.

Comment: Thanke you for your nice conterbuting but you know its hurting when you buy a broken phone and then when u take it to the store the seller is telling you that you have to wait for 2 weeks to repair it. I paid money who is going to be responsible for the time and money I spent for it....I have to go to the shop 4 times to repair it.

Comment: Yes, It's not an ideal situation, but the issue seems to be more with your retailer than the device.  As much as no-one wants a product to break, especially when new, a small percentage out of the millions sold every month do break.  When it does, you hope your retailer has high standards for customer care, and unfortunately some do not and rely on the legal minimum etc.